# Extra form fields added in Django form render

Tags: python, django

I've got a django form setup as follows:

forms.py

```
class TestimonialForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    designation = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    testimonial = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control test-form-area'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Testimonials
```

models.py

```
class Testimonials(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    test = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    credentials = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py

```
def add_testimonial(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TestimonialForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)

            return index(request)
        else:
            print form.errors

    else:
        form = TestimonialForm()

    return render_to_response('/add_testimonial.html', {'form': form}, context)
```

On render, I see the three main fields that I defined in forms.py that have the classes form-control added to them. However, I also see two extra fields that have no styling attached to them. Any idea what's going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form defines the fields name, designation and testimonial, but the model provides name, test and credentials. So the name field gets redefined with the extra styling, but the other two fields are simply added to the default fields provided by the model. If you want to override them, you need to use the same names.